# Call cleanup function once in React18 Strict Mode

Tags: reactjs

In React18, Strict mode behavior is changed like `mount` -> `unmount` -> `mount`.

Due to this new behavior, if there is a code the following,  it doesnt work as expected.

```js
const abort = new AbortController();
... // abort API call when unmount
useEffect(() => {
  return () => abort.cancel(); // <- API call is aborted before unexpectedly due to the new Strict Mode behavior
}, [])
```

How can I avoid calling cleanup function with Strict Mode?

If possible, the same code should work in both development and production mode.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The first API call gets aborted but I guess second should be going right

Comment: The current logic is that when abort is called, API wouldn't be called after that. I expect not to be called cleanup function at first, but it seems hard to do it. Probably removing strict mode is the solution